# Dynamic type in Xamarin.iOS with Realm

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, realm

I have an API in which the value of a key can come as int, string or dictionary.

I was using `object` keyword as the *type* for the value and it worked fine.

But once I implemented `Realm` compiler gave me an error.

```
Error: Fody/RealmWeaver: MyClass.Value is a 'System.Object' which is not yet supported.
```

Ok fine so `object` is not supported by `Realm`. Then I tried using `dynamic` keyword as the type. I got the following error.

```
Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create' (CS0656)
```

Googling this led me to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2921#issuecomment-395002124) comment which says **dynamic keyword is not allowed on iOS because JIT compilation is not allowed**.

So what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The Realm weaver only supports a subset of known types

- String
- ByteArray
- Char
- Byte
- Int16
- Int32
- Int64
- Single
- Double
- Boolean
- DateTimeOffset
- And the nullable variants of the above

as defined here https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/Weaver/RealmWeaver.Fody/ModuleWeaver.cs#L34

So you are falling through to this exception
https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/Weaver/RealmWeaver.Fody/ModuleWeaver.cs#L481

So you need to change `MyClass.Value` to one of the known types